# How to properly parse string using preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have some alerts setup, that are emailed to me on a regular occurrence and in those emails I get content that looks like this:

```
     2002 Volkswagen Eurovan Clean title - $2000
```

That is the general consistent format. Those are also links that are clickable.
I have a script that's setup already that will extract the links from the body string properly, but what I am looking for is basically the year and the price from those titles that come in. There is the possibility of more than one being listed within the email.

So my question is, how can I use preg_match_all to properly grab all the possibilities so that I can then explode them to get the first piece of data (year) and the last piece of data (price)? Would I take the approach to see if I can match based on digits as it's presumed the format will generally be the same?

Comment: Can you provide your attempts?

Comment: `/^([0-9]{4})|(\$[0-9]+)$/` this will match strings that are either a 4-digit number at the start of the string, or a dollar sign with number at the end.

Comment: My current attempt is this: '/^(\d+)/i'

Comment: castis - doesn't seem to work. The output is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can try matching the 4 digits starting with `19` and `20` and name these captures a *year*, and the digits after `$` a *price*, and use anchors `^` and `$` if these values are always at the beginning and end of a string:

```
^(?'year'\b(?:19|20)\d{2}\b)|(?'price'\$\d+)$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vT9aA9/3)

Sample [IDEONE code](http://ideone.com/e0M5Qr):

```
$re = "/^(?'year'\\b(?:19|20)\\d{2}\\b)|(?'price'\\$\\d+)$/"; 
$str = "2002 Volkswagen Eurovan Clean title - \$2100"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r(array_filter($matches["year"]));
print_r(array_filter($matches["price"]));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2002
)
Array
(
    [1] => $2100
)
```

Comment: What's interesting is when I use your $str, it works, but when I use mine, it doesn't.

Comment: And what's yours? Could you share (best via ideone.com)